# Time does not sync

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, time

I have set time to sync with Internet servers in "Time and Date Settings". No error shown there. However time does bot sync and is off by several days. `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` tells the respective service unit could not be found. How to fix this?

Edit:

The notebook does not have main battery, and maybe secondary battery, if any, is dead, so I want time to be set from Internet ASAP after boot even if a user does not log in.

```
$ timedatectl status
               Local time: su 2023-06-25 11:53:30 EEST  
           Universal time: su 2023-06-25 08:53:30 UTC   
                 RTC time: pe 1980-01-04 00:15:56       
                Time zone: Europe/Helsinki (EEST, +0300)
System clock synchronized: no                           
              NTP service: n/a                          
          RTC in local TZ: no
     
$ timedatectl timesync-status
Failed to query server: The name org.freedesktop.timesync1 was not provided by any .service files

$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.

$ LC_ALL=C systemctl status ntp
* ntp.service - Network Time Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-03-27 20:56:59 EEST; 2 months 28 days ago
       Docs: man:ntpd(8)
   Main PID: 593 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 27 20:55:19 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 65.21.58.9
Mar 27 20:56:22 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 95.216.71.38
Mar 27 20:56:23 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 95.216.218.15
Mar 27 20:56:25 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 91.189.91.157
Mar 27 20:56:25 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 62.241.198.253
Mar 27 20:56:26 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: Soliciting pool server 65.109.217.171
Mar 27 20:56:59 jarnos-8510w ntpd[593]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
Mar 27 20:56:59 jarnos-8510w systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Service...
Mar 27 20:56:59 jarnos-8510w systemd[1]: ntp.service: Succeeded.
Mar 27 20:56:59 jarnos-8510w systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Service.

$ systemctl status chrony
Unit chrony.service could not be found.
```

`ntp` and `sntp` is installed, `chrony` is not.

Comment: Could you please provide full output (in your question) of the following commands: `timedatectl status`, `timedatectl timesync-status`, `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` and `systemctl status ntp`. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please specify if you knowingly installed another timesync daemon, such as `ntp` or `chrony`?

Comment: Also if I might add: `systemctl status chrony` to the list of commands. If I'm not mistaken, if you are using chrony and you run `timedatectl status` it should say `NTP service: active` even if/when the ntp service cannot be found.

Comment: @ArturMeinild After editing, I installed `systemd-timesyncd` and removed `ntp`. That did not change the output of `systemctl status ntp`, but `timedatectl status` now tells NTP service is active. Should I remove `sntp`, too?

Comment: @mchid please see above.

Comment: Seems to be working after the changes.

Comment: @jarno I think you should keep sntp. From what I understand and based on [the `systemd-timesyncd` release notes](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v213/NEWS#L5) and [other answers like this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504387/), `systemd-timesyncd` uses `sntp` by default. Not sure why `sntp` is not showing as a dependency of `systemd-timesyncd`, however.

Answer (score 1):

Command `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd` helped in this case. It also removed `ntp`.